# AWS lambda problem with deployment - not enough permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When I try to deploy AWS lambda from Visual Studio I get this error

```
Fetching ECR authorization token to use to login with the docker CLI
Error logging on with the docker CLI: User: arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/@Infra/aws-toolkit-visualstudio-637706142753914780 is not authorized to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: * because no identity-based policy allows the ecr:GetAuthorizationToken action
```

The IAM role I am using has these permissions:

AmazonS3FullAccess

AmazonAPIGatewayAdministrator

AmazonElasticContainerRegistryPublicFullAccess

AWSLambda_FullAccess

If I extend this list by adding AdministratorAccess then deployment is successful but I would like to limit permissions to only these which are needed.

Any idea how to extend permission to fix this problem?
I already have there AmazonElasticContainerRegistryPublicFullAccess so I would  expect it should be enough.

I passed fake numbers in in the error message because of security.

Comment: You need  something like `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser`. 
As the error message says`AmazonElasticContainerRegistryPublicFullAccess` does not provide access to push private images to ECR.

Comment: Inspect what `AmazonElasticContainerRegistryPublicFullAccess` actually does, can easily be done in the IAM console and then check if `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken` is granted on `*` - don't just expect stuff.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear how to "limit permissions to only these which are needed"?

Comment: Adding AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can add an [inline policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#inline-policies) to your role with just `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken` permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please **don't change**: `"Resource": "*"`. This is how it should be for `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken`.

If you pass this error, and get other access deny, add the missing permissions to the policy.

Comment: Does the arn of the resource token change often?

Comment: @lynkfox `GetAuthorizationToken` does not have a resource. Thus `*` is used.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Adding AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser solved the problem.